# Level NaN must be same as name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, nan

I am trying to count how many times NaN appears in a column of a dataframe using this code:

```
count = enron_df.loc['salary'].count('NaN')
```

But every time i run this i get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Level NaN must be same as name (None)'
```

I searched around the web a lot trying to find a solution, but to no avail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `NaN`s are [missing values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html):

```
enron_df = pd.DataFrame({'salary':[np.nan, np.nan, 1, 5, 7]})
print (enron_df)
   salary
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     1.0
3     5.0
4     7.0

count = enron_df['salary'].isna().sum()
#alternative
#count = enron_df['salary'].isnull().sum()
print (count)
2
```

If `NaN`s are `strings`:

```
enron_df = pd.DataFrame({'salary':['NaN', 'NaN', 1, 5, 'NaN']})
print (enron_df)
  salary
0    NaN
1    NaN
2      1
3      5
4    NaN

count = enron_df['salary'].eq('NaN').sum()
#alternative
#count = (enron_df['salary'] == 'NaN').sum()
print (count)
3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second solution works... seems like the values in my enron_df are strings.

Comment: @IanDzindo - And all another values are numeric? It is expected values are strings?

Comment: Yes, they're supposed to be strings.

Answer (score 5):

By definition, `count` omits `NaN`s and `size` does not.

Thus, a simple difference should do

```
count = enron_df['salary'].size - enron_df['salary'].count()
```

Comment: I just answered with this and didn't see yours.  I deleted mine `len(enron_df) - enron_df.salary.count()`.  Also, OP had it wrong.  You don't use `enron_df.loc['salary']` to get at a column.  You want to remove the `.loc` in your answer.

Comment: @piRSquared yeah nice remarks, I had just copied/pasted and added `size` and `count`. Just edited, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
count = df.loc[df['salary']=='NaN'].shape[0]
```

Or maybe better:

```
count = df.loc[df['salary']=='NaN', 'salary'].size
```

And, going down your path, you'd need something like this:

```
count = df.loc[:, 'salary'].str.count('NaN').sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also value counts with the `dropna` argument

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

enron_df = pd.DataFrame({'salary':[np.nan, np.nan, 1, 5, 7]})

enron_df.salary.value_counts(dropna=False)
#NaN     2
# 7.0    1
# 5.0    1
# 1.0    1
#Name: salary, dtype: int64
```

And if you just want the number, just select `np.NaN` from value counts. (If they are strings `'NaN'`, then just replace `np.NaN` with `'NaN'`)

```
enron_df.salary.value_counts(dropna=False)[np.NaN]
#2
```